# Java JTextField view from the Right

Tags: java, view, jtextfield, visibility

I have a `JTextField` that I'm trying to get to automatically view from the Right (Not align to the right), so if the text is to long for the `JTextField` it will display the last characters in the String instead of the beginning.

Ive been searching for ages trying to locate an answer but keep coming up with aligning.

The 2 images below show what i get and what I'm after, the text is "123456789_123", the `JTextField` is only big enough to contain the "123456789" but i want to see the "56789_123" instead without having to  focus on the field. (i can use something other than a `JTextField` if needed, tried a `JTextArea` but had the same issue).

[What i Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzJj0.jpg)

[What I'm after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2j5g.jpg)

I can not just make the Field bigger as I'm restricted by other Objects in my program. Usually the text fits fine but every now and then its too big.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around.

you create a JScrollPane, make its vertical and horizontal bars invisible by setting there dimensions to 0,0. then scroll to end using 'setValue' to max.

hope this helps anyone trying to do something similar.

```
JTextArea editArea2 = new JTextArea(5,5);
    editArea2.setText("123456789_12345");
    editArea2.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    asd = new Dimension();
    asd.height = 20;
    asd.width = 70;
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(editArea2);
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(asd); 
    scrollPane.setMaximumSize(asd);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize (new Dimension(0,0));
    scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setPreferredSize (new Dimension(0,0));
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setMaximumSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue( scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum() );
```